# Return value from a test.describe of Mocha test framework

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, mocha.js

I am not sure how to put the question so it makes sense. Let's say, I have Mocha test and I want to return an object after the test. For example:

```
var test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing');
test.describe('Test', function() {
    test.describe('#login()', function() {
        test.before(function(done){
            //driver = create driver object here
            done();
        });
        test.after(function(done){
            driver.quit();
            done();
        });
        test.it('', function(done){
            //code
            done()
        });
    });
});
```

I want to return driver object, but it seems not work. I tried to `return 'Test text'`, but also nothing happens. Is it possible to return a value within test wrap-up Mocha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mocha does not provide any way to return a useable value from the callback passed to `describe`. If what you are aiming for is to have your `driver` instance available to the uppermost `describe`, then do this:

```
var test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing');
test.describe('Test', function() {
    // This is available to everything inside the callback.
    var driver;
    test.before(function(){
        driver = // whatever...
    });
    test.after(function(){
        driver.quit();
    });

    test.describe('#login()', function() {
        test.it('', function(){

        });
    });
});
```

Note that I've removed the `done` callbacks because `selenium-webdriver/testing` actually gives you wrappers around the basic Mocha functions. These wrappers take into account the `ControlFlow` created by Selenium. See [the documentation](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/module_selenium-webdriver_testing.html) for an example of a test.